# How Do i connect sails to mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, nosql

Im new to sails Js and mongodb. I am absolutely a newbie.

Problem:
I already have a user collection on my mongodb database. I want to connect it to sails to display the list of collection.

Ive seen sails js documentations. I already installed sails-mongo adapter and edited the connection.js....

```
 module.exports = {
    // this is my model
  attributes: {

    firstname: {
    type: 'string'
    }


  },
  findUser: function(opts,callback){
      ///// How am I going to connect to mongo and query the users ?

     //// user.find('John Doe') wont work here.
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Run: `npm install sails-mongo`
2. in `config/connections.js` uncomment section related to mongo and enter necessary info there

   someMongodbServer: {
           adapter: 'sails-mongo',
           host: 'mongohost.com',
           port: 55915,
           user: 'user',
           password: 'password',
           database: 'dbname'
       },
3. in `config/models.js` enter you connection adapter variable

   ...
   connection: 'someMongodbServer',
   ...
4. done

**EDIT**: 
In order to get the data from database use the following:

```
User.find({firstname: 'John Doe'}).exec(function(error, user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

Comment: Do i need to add something to get the data collections/tables from my mongo?